# How do I store reported comments/photos in firestore?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, database-design

I want to learn firestore and to this end I created small project which replicates instagram. Not all functionalities of course, just the very basics - photo sharing, comments and the possibility to report a comment or a photo.

This is how my current collections look like:

`users` -> user_id -> [username, email]
`following` -> user_id -> `usersFollowing` -> [list of user ids]

//my most difficult collection

`posts` -> user_id -> `userPosts` -> post_id (this is the photo id) -> [caption, creationDate, url [likes], [comments]] //`likes` and `comments` are subcollections where I respectively store ids of people who liked the photo and in comments I store the id of the people who commented and the actual comment

Here is my question. I want to be able to report photo or a comment (as abusive, inappropriate, etc). I thought of creating collection `reports` where I will have two subcollections `photos` and `comments`; Each one of this subcollection will have a doc `photoId` or `commentId`  and each doc will contain the following info: `reportedBy` <- the user_id of the person who reported the photo/comment; `date` <-the date it was reported

So far so good. However, if a photo/comment have lots of reports eventually I may want to delete it. How do I do that? I have only the photo/comment id stored in my `Reports` collection. I guess this is a sign that my collection is not properly structured? Maybe alongside `reportedBy` and `date` fields I should store several more fields: like `userId` <- the id of the user which created that post (photo or a comment) and `postId` <- the id of the post to which that particular comment belongs. Is that a good approach or not really? Are there any better suggestions?

Comment: Any updates on this one? If the answer resolved your issue, you can accept it by clicking tick icon so that others know the issue is resolved else feel free to ask further questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually stored a collection of reports with the specific post ID as document ID something like this:

[image]

There's also a sub-collections containing documents with reporter UID, their comment and maybe some meta data.
Whenever a user reports a post, just increment the value in the report document as well so you can have better statistics.

Coming to the part where you want to remove the post when it just gets reported a lot. You can try [Firestore Triggers for Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) which will run a function when a post is reported ***each time***. Then if the report is count is too high, you can delete it.

This might be a bit expensive so running a [scheduled cloud function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) every hour or so will be economical. Just run the function periodically and check for any posts over a specific amount of reports and delete/hide it.